# Ubuntu 16 freezing and restarting session

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

My UBUNTU 16.04 is freezing and restarting the session. This is always happening while I'm using LibreOffice 5.1.6.2.

I found this using DMESG:

```
[ 1435.886268] [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:0:0x85dffffb, in Xorg [1070], reason: Hang on render ring, action: reset
[ 1435.886295] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[ 1435.886380] [drm] RC6 on
[ 1435.900900] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[ 1447.874730] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[ 1447.874799] [drm] RC6 on
[ 1447.893257] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[ 1450.993759] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 5c:a3:9d:f9:68:b8 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1454.741738] wlp3s0: authenticate with 5c:a3:9d:f9:68:b8
```

Which makes me think It is having some GUI problems, which is weird it only happens while I'm using LibreOffice, while I'm programming (Qt creator) or using the chrome, there is no session's reboot.

Can it be my Integrated graphic card? there is any way to know what is happening with LibreOffice to understand why is freezing the PC and make it restart the session?

------------ New Log because the problem continues------

```
[12174.024936] [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:0:0x85dffffb, in Xorg [1012], reason: Hang on render ring, action: reset
[12174.024970] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[12174.025052] [drm] RC6 on
[12174.039580] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[12191.997872] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[12191.997951] [drm] RC6 on
[12192.011963] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[12203.997883] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
[12203.997950] [drm] RC6 on
[12204.014354] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[12204.187373] show_signal_msg: 13 callbacks suppressed
[12204.187376] kactivitymanage[8396]: segfault at 7fa4c7d97cd0 ip 00007fa49bda8261 sp 00007ffdf19e7cc8 error 4 in libQt5Sql.so.5.5.1[7fa49bd94000+3f000]
[12207.505097] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 5c:a3:9d:f9:68:b8 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and have been looking around and found this thread
[LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 crashes ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964576/libreoffice-5-1-6-2-crashes-ubuntu-16-04-64-bit)

Based on that I just tried this

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04
```

Then:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core
```

And finally:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-input-all
```

So far, so good. I haven't had any more crashes since I did this. But it's only been a few days. Will feel better after a week with no more crashes.

Comment: So far, so good. I haven't had any more crashes since I did this. But it's only been a few days. Will feel better after a week with no more crashes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I did several changes at different moments and now it is working, so I cant test your solution for acceptance. If there is someone else that has the problem and can give us feedback

Comment: Just to let you know that in the almost two weeks since making these changes  I haven't had anymore crashes of this type, so seems that in my case this was the issue.