# LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 crashes ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, crash

At my wit's end. Running LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 (the std repo version) on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit).

```
azed@azed-H270N:~$ uname -a
Linux azed-H270N 4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 22:42:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

LO has always had a tendency to "hang" on my 16.04 system, but now it is regularly taking down the whole system.

Doing anything quickly in LO - sweep-selecting text, executing two commands in quick succession - seems to bring-on the problem.

The size of the document may also be a factor. The problem has tended to occur when I am working on a long (600 page, 3.6MB) doc, but this may only be because I tend not to work on short docs for very long.

**Symptoms**:

The whole system freezes. The mouse pointer remains mobile, but the system is otherwise unresponsive. After a few minutes of stasis, the system crashes back to the login screen.

After logging back-in, I am greeted by the LO document-recovery dialogue. The doc comes back OK, but all work done after the last LO autosave is lost.

After one crash, LO is much more likely to crash again.

**Steps taken**:

1. I have increased the memory used for the LO graphics cache to 190MB, and the memory / object to 12MB, but this has not improved things.
2. I have also tried calling LO from a terminal with gtk2 rather than gtk3, using:

   ```
   SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk libreoffice
   ```

   as detailed here:

   [Force LibreOffice 5.1.2.2 to use gtk2 instead of gtk3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765950/force-libreoffice-5-1-2-2-to-use-gtk2-instead-of-gtk3)

   But no joy/improvement (didn't seem to change anything).
3. After the last crash, I examined `~/.xsession-errors`, `/var/log/dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog`. The last yielded:

   ```
   Oct 12 16:20:38 azed-H270N gnome-session[1707]: ** (soffice:1998): WARNING **: Unknown event notification 36
   Oct 12 16:24:26 azed-H270N gnome-session[1707]: ** (soffice:1998): WARNING **: Unknown event notification 36
   Oct 12 16:24:26 azed-H270N systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
   Oct 12 16:24:26 azed-H270N systemd-tmpfiles[2712]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log", ignoring.
   Oct 12 16:24:26 azed-H270N systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
   Oct 12 16:24:38 azed-H270N gnome-session[1707]: ** (soffice:1998): WARNING **: Unknown event notification 36
   Oct 12 16:29:12 azed-H270N gnome-session[1707]: message repeated 3 times: [ ** (soffice:1998): WARNING **: Unknown event notification 36]
   Oct 12 16:34:46 azed-H270N org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer[1551]: ** (zeitgeist-fts:2105): WARNING **: Unable to get info on application://nautilus-autostart.desktop
   Oct 12 16:39:46 azed-H270N systemd[1]: Starting Automatically fetch and run repair assertions...
   Oct 12 16:39:46 azed-H270N snap-repair[2949]: error: cannot use snap-repair on a classic system
   Oct 12 16:39:46 azed-H270N systemd[1]: Started Automatically fetch and run repair assertions.
   Oct 12 16:49:33 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2426.455211] [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:0:0x85dffffb, in Xorg [946], reason: Hang on render ring, action: reset
   Oct 12 16:49:33 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2426.455238] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
   Oct 12 16:49:33 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2426.455284] [drm] RC6 on
   Oct 12 16:49:33 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2426.471991] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
   Oct 12 16:49:51 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2444.435136] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
   Oct 12 16:49:51 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2444.435196] [drm] RC6 on
   Oct 12 16:49:51 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2444.449146] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
   Oct 12 16:50:11 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2464.434387] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
   Oct 12 16:50:11 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2464.434449] [drm] RC6 on
   Oct 12 16:50:11 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2464.446462] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
   Oct 12 16:50:31 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2484.433590] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
   Oct 12 16:50:31 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2484.433655] [drm] RC6 on
   Oct 12 16:50:31 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2484.448736] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
   Oct 12 16:50:49 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2502.416895] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
   Oct 12 16:50:49 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2502.416960] [drm] RC6 on
   Oct 12 16:50:49 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2502.431102] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
   Oct 12 16:51:09 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2522.416124] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
   Oct 12 16:51:09 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2522.416192] [drm] RC6 on
   Oct 12 16:51:09 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2522.432185] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
   Oct 12 16:51:24 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2537.204555] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
   Oct 12 16:51:26 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2538.876556] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
   Oct 12 16:51:27 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2540.500557] sysrq: SysRq : This sysrq operation is disabled.
   Oct 12 16:51:29 azed-H270N kernel: [ 2542.415352] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
   ```

**Questions**:

Is my problem related to this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1574266

would upgrading to a newer version of LO from the official LO ppa help matters?

Has anyone else come across this prob?

New solution ideas?

Any help very gratefully received. LO is a key app for me. If I can't rely on it, it makes my 16.04 system virtually useless.

Comment: same problem showed up on my desktop last week. No new apps installed...just updates. I ended up just removing libre-office from the system and switching to WPS office. http://wps-community.org/

Comment: I have similar problem with my fresh Ubuntu 18.04LTS install. Please, if you know a solution, let me know in thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096784/how-to-fix-ubuntu-18-04lts-freezes

Answer (score 2):

I get on the right track.

After another crash, I examined `/var/log/syslog` and turned up this:

```
Oct 17 20:01:14 azed-H270N kernel: [38304.615927] [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:0:0x85dffffb, in Xorg [969], reason: Hang on render ring, action: reset
Oct 17 20:01:14 azed-H270N kernel: [38304.615958] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
Oct 17 20:01:14 azed-H270N kernel: [38304.616003] [drm] RC6 on
Oct 17 20:01:14 azed-H270N kernel: [38304.632462] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
Oct 17 20:01:26 azed-H270N kernel: [38316.580869] drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
```

This suggested to me that the problem was indeed [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1575301). Post #6 in the above thread refers to the tendency of systems using the i915 driver to hang as "a well-known problem with the i915 driver".

For purposes of comparison, if anyone else has this problem, here's my kit:

```
azed@azed-H270N:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for azed:
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
version: 06
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
resources: irq:132 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**OK, so what to do?**

Post #12 in the above thread recommended installing `xserver-xorg-video-intel` as a fix:

But when I tried doing this with Synaptic, the system wouldn't let me. Another package, `xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04`, had to be uninstalled first. Unfortunately, my system wasn't keen to do the uninstall.

A little research revealed that the above was installed at the time of a 16.04 point-release earlier in the year. This info was consistent with the behaviour of my system, which ran OK last year.

**Solution**:

Found a possible solution [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/02/install-remove-enablement-stacks-ubuntu-16-04/). Following the advice given at the above w/page, I did this:

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-input-all
```

**Note**: I omitted `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` from the version of this last command given in the link above, as the 64-bit versions of these packages seemed to be already installed in my system.

Having made the above changes, I rebooted. The system came back fine.

**Result**:

That was a week ago. I haven't had a single "hang" since. My 16.04 system now seems to be working fine.

By the way, I don't think the hang-problem has anything much to do with Libreoffice. I am still getting /var/log/syslog-warnings like:

```
Oct 24 09:52:57 azed-H270N gnome-session[1684]: (soffice:2017): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large
Oct 24 09:53:05 azed-H270N org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1548]: ** (gvfsd:1619): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument
Oct 24 09:53:07 azed-H270N org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1548]: message repeated 2 times: [ ** (gvfsd:1619): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument]
Oct 24 09:54:26 azed-H270N gnome-session[1684]: ** (soffice:2017): WARNING **: Unknown event notification 36
```

but these don't seem to be causing trouble. I think my problem was a problem with Xorg. I made the association with LibreOffice because I tended to be using it (I use it a lot) whenever the system crashed.

Hope all this helps someone.

**Note**: if the above solution doesn't work for you, the changes can be reverted with:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

I think that's it, anyway. See here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled into this problem as well. I even have the same graphics hardware. I seem to have fixed it with less drastic measures. I turned off Java and OpenCL in the Tools->Options dialog (Java checkbox under "Advanced").

Seems much better now.

Comment: Updated today to NVidia driver, and it seems a solution, at least for today!